# A non-i.i.d observations in a Bayesian inference problem

Tags: bayesian, sampling, sample

Suppose we have a simple Bayesian network which has two variables $x$ and $y$, $x$ is the parent of $y$. We sample $M$ $x$s independently based on $P(x)$, named $x_1,\ldots,x_M$, and for every $x_i$, we sample $N$ $y$s independently based on $P(y|x)$, named $y_{i1},\ldots,y_{iN}$. In this way we have $MN$ observations $(x_i,y_{ij}),i=1,\ldots,M,j=1,\ldots,N$.

Such observations are not i.i.d observations. Is there a term to call this type of observations? Are there any papers or materials to research the Bayesian inference problem based on such type of observations? (with more complex models and perhaps hidden variables)

Answer (score 2):

This is called hierarchical data.  The formalism and inference methods of Bayesian networks can already deal with such data.  In your example, the appropriate Bayesian network would have $x_1, ..., x_M$ as variable nodes and $y_{i1}, ..., y_{iN}$ as children of $x_i$.  This network automatically encodes the independence statements listed in the question.  Any standard inference algorithm applied to this network (such as belief propagation or Gibbs sampling) will make use of those independencies.